# Why does Angular add an empty <option> if the value exist in the provided options?

Tags: angularjs

I have read on many occasions that Angular tends to add an empty `option` at the beginning of the `select` element if the value of the `model` does not exist among the offered `options`.

However, I have a `model` whose value is set to `0` from the start, and `0` is provided as one of the options in the select element as well, yet there is still one empty `option` above my own `options`. It disappears after the actual `option` whose value is `0` gets selected.

Why is this and how do I get rid of it?

A very simple example of the problem I am experiencing is displayed here: http://jsfiddle.net/yuvnz7wr/

The javascript code:

```
var app = angular.module('Module', []);
app.controller('Test', function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = 0;
    $scope.options = [{
        id: 0,
        name: 'Zero'
    }, {
        id: 1,
        name: 'One'
    }];
});
```

The HTML code:

```
<div ng-app="Module">
    <div ng-controller="Test as test">{{model}}
        <select ng-model="model">
            <option ng-repeat="option in options" ng-value="option.id">{{option.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use ngoptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better use `ng-options` and `ng-init` directives for `<select>` with angular:

```
<div ng-app="Module">
    <div ng-controller="Test as test">{{model}}
        <select ng-model="model" ng-init="model = options[0].id" ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in options"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```